# CSS Toggle arrow left and right with just css

Tags: css, sass

I was to create a toggle button in css where I have something like the image attached.

It needs to have an arrow pointing left or right.

Can this be done using just css?

[image]

Comment: Yes you can achieve this using CSS. Check out `:before` and `:after` in CSS. You can use `transform` property to rotate the arrow lines.

Comment: I'm not totally clear what you want. Is it that you want the arrow image to change from left to right on a hover or a click or what? Please also include your basic code and show any attempts  you have already made.

Comment: No, I don't want it to be an image just css. I made an image just to show what I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow only css:

```css
.arrow {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}

.right {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.left {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.up {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.down {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<i class="arrow right"></i>
<br/>
<i class="arrow left"></i>
```

EDIT:

Yes, you can create a toggle arrow making triangles with the border trick and toggle with the checkbox trick.

```css
.toggle-arrow {
      position: relative;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .toggle-arrow .real-checkbox {
      clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0); /* Hide checkbox */
      position: absolute;
    }
    .toggle-arrow .real-checkbox + .toggle-button {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
    }
    .toggle-arrow .real-checkbox + .toggle-button::before {
      content: "";
      display: inline-block;
      /* Arrow */
      border: solid black;
      border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 3px;
      /* Right arrow */
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
    .toggle-arrow .real-checkbox:checked + .toggle-button::before {
      /* Left arrow */
      transform: rotate(135deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    }
```

```html
<label class="toggle-arrow">
  <input type="checkbox" class="real-checkbox">
  <div class="toggle-button"></div>
</label>
```

Change the right CSS property with the left if you want to start with the arrow pointing differently.

Comment: Can I make it toggle between left hand right with just css?

Comment: @ojy2021 Did you need the js part? Because you need to toggle changing the class from `arrow left` to `arrow right`.

Comment: I wanted to know if it can be done without javascript

Comment: That depends on how you actually “toggle” your button, and whether that causes a property change that CSS can react to.

Comment: @ojy2021 I edited my answer after figuring out what you meant.

Comment: Perfect...I appreciate your help. Thanks